# How do I add IN-APP PURCHASE capability when doing a build (ios)

Tags: nativescript

How do I add IN-APP PURCHASE capability when doing a build.

I'm specifying the development provision file name when doing the build and I can't see my purchases when I run the app.

I've added the IAP to my APP-ID in itunes.

Do I need to edit the xcodeproj file manually to add the in-app purchase capability.

If so - any way to add it on the command-line.

If not - when should the xcodeproj file be edited - before which TNS command.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may do it the first time - edit Xcode project to enable in app purchases, then copy the entitlements file from Xcode project folder and place it in your *App_Resources*. Finally you will have to update *build.xcconfig* with the name of the file. For example,

```
CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = appname/filename.entitlements
```

Comment: I did a project build and then went into the platforms folder and found the xcodeproj file, opened xcode and manually selected a provision and enabled IAP and closed xcode. But I can't find the entittlements file.

Comment: I was able to create an entitlements file - but it's empty. How can I add the IAP capability to it. Thanks